# julia Handling time difference in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia, lag

I have a dataframe with a date time column. As you can see below, I've managed to
read it and even transform the date.

```
using CSV
using Dates
using DataFrames
using DataFramesMeta
csv = CSV.read(IOBuffer("""
date,Amount
2023-12-27 18:40,4
2023-12-27 18:45,254
2023-12-27 18:50,24
2023-12-27 18:55,24
2023-12-27 19:00,5
"""),DataFrame)
transform!(csv,[:date].=>ByRow(s->DateTime(s,dateformat"y-m-d H:M"))=>:date)
```

But I want to calculate the time difference between rows. I'm coming from R where I'd write:

```
df |> mutate(diff=date-lag(date)) # (etc)
```

I've no idea how to do this in Julia. I figure it's another transform, but the lag has got me bamboozled! Any help appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a diff() function in Julia DataFrames like pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904666/is-there-a-diff-function-in-julia-dataframes-like-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
csv.diff = vcat([0],[csv.date[i]-csv.date[i-1] for i=2:length(csv.date)])
```

This adds a new column called `diff` into the DataFrame `csv` that is the difference between each successive row, initializing the first one as zero because there is no row before it to compare (but you could also define that differently if you want to).

Comment: Thanks that works and shows me julia syntax I'd have never suspected. 

I also found ...
```
transform!(csv,[:date,:date] => ((x,y)->x-lag(y,1)) =>:ldate)
```
which works but doesn't handle the first row.